# How to post on Google + in android app

Tags: android, integration, google-plus

I want to post on google plust using my own app like face book integration in app.
Google has released some api code. I have configured that. I am able to fetch the list of my post. It works fine. ut now I want to post on google plus and I have no clue what to do.
Can anyone help me out ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm also trying to do the same thing right now. I want to post a photo, but according to the public APIs, it is read-only for public data and personal data for login.

Look into the Plus class and the ActivityObjectAttachmentsImage. You can ready the photos or jsut the Activity, but can you insert().execute? I see that is how they do it in other Google API calls